# Can you protect and then unprotect your own questions?

Tags: support, protected-questions

I read the guidelines and and if I understand it correctly users with at least 15,000 reputation can protect or unprotect any question at least a day old. I cannot find out anywhere if this also applies to your own questions and if you don't meet the 15,000 reputation qualification.
It would make sense that the original poster of a question should be able to remove the protection. Is this the case?

Comment: You should not be able to protect your own questions <15k, for various reasons. About unprotecting however I am also curious.

Comment: Why would you? It's for your own protection!

Comment: Given the question, it sounds like you don't understand what protecting a question means, or why its used.  That's exactly why users need 15k rep to have access to the privilege.

Answer (score 5):

No; the original poster is not expected to know the subtleties of (un)protection, and in almost all cases would be unable to do a good job. Some would protect all the questions they ask (which is unnecessary and counterproductive), some would never protect any question (which is a bit of a waste of the privilege), and in any case, a lot of time would be spent pondering whether to apply protection when 99% of questions do not need it.

As it stands, most 15k users seldom protect any questions; Community ♦ is just too efficient at its job and catches a good 80-90% of those few questions that do need protection. (I've had the privilege on one site for a few months, and I can't remember if I've used it yet.)

Comment: @iDebug: I was referring to ELL, actually, which hadn't graduated yet. I was exercising 20k privileges before beta ended. (I still need 801 rep on Space to hit protect/unprotect, even in beta.)

Comment: When did ELL guaduate? It seems it's graduated as of now.

Comment: @iDebug: [About a month later](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2945/new-site-design) (or rather, that's when the second phase completed, with site design and higher privileges released simultaneously).

Comment: To answer your last question, you protected a question three times: http://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/797605/questions-protected-unprotected-by-specified-user?UserId=10820

Comment: @Glorfindel: I didn't really *ask* a question, but thanks for the stats! I seem to have used it more for unprotecting, and mostly shortly after getting it.